# MySQL Selective Show Status

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL provides a neat way to keep tabs on the status of the db server via `SHOW STATUS`.  The only issue is that the information that is returned is too voluminous.  For my needs I only need to get hold of a handful of values - say `UPTIME`, `THREADS_RUNNING`, `THREADS_CREATED` etc.  I am unable to figure out the right syntax to use to issue such a query.

```
'SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE "uptime"'
```

gives me uptime but I would like to get a few more values in a single query.  I'd be most grateful to anyone who might be able to tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All this information is available in the `information_schema` database, `GLOBAL_STATUS` table.

Your MySQL user needs `read` permission tho:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.`GLOBAL_STATUS`
WHERE VARIABLE_NAME IN ('UPTIME', 'THREADS_RUNNING')
```

Comment: Thank you.SHOW GLOBAL STATUS WHERE variable_name IN ('uptime','connections',...) works nicely.

Comment: @DroidOS `SHOW GLOBAL` is a little limited but basic queries seem to work. If you need a more complex query, the whole information schema offers a LOT of interesting information, refere to the manual as per Vatev's link. Have fun :)

Answer (score 2):

When you need to query system variables, schemas, etc... you should look for it in [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html). In this case you probably need `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_STATUS`.

Comment: You have a valid point.  However, all I am looking for here is to incorporate some information regarding DB status in a periodic poll of server health

Comment: You should probably check out some of the already invented monitoring systems (e.g. Nagios). They are usually complex to install and configure, but also offer a lot of good features.